# How to access properties of a Tridion component like schema name based on which it is created in aspx page?

Tags: tridion

I am customizing the ribbon tool bar by adding a button to it in TRIDION 2011 SP1 version.
When I click on the button it will open an aspx page.Inside that aspx page I need to access the name of the schema used to create that component before creating the component itself(I mean to say while creating the component itself).

Please provide me a way to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already tried to access all the components present in the folder using webdav url. My aim is to open a popup page which consists some dropdown lists which will be populated based on the schema used to create the component. The main problem here is all this should be happened before saving the component.(So I cannot access the tcm uri id to get the schema name,because tcm uri will be created once we save the component)

Comment: Have you tried any of the MANY tutorials and examples on GUI Extensions yet? Just google for "tridion gui extension" and you'll find quite a few, including step-by-steps. If you have tried that already, then I think you may be missing some Tridion fundamentals...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass it to your popup. The URI of the Schema is available on the Component model object within the CME - so your button command can access it and pass it to the popup (in the URL, for example).

```
var schemaId = $display.getView().getItem().getSchemaId();
```

Comment: Can you please provide me the link/API where i can get more methods regarding Component model object. As my furthur work requires getting the value with in the controls to the popup. Any guidelines would help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's any API documentation for that. But if you use a developer tool (such as the one built into your browser), you can see all of the methods available to you.

Comment: you can find the documentation on http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion the one you are looking for is the "SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 GUI Extension API"

Comment: @PeterKjaer Can you please provide me a command which will return the current component tcmURI.(Component is already saved and tcmURI is existing). Thanks in advance.

Comment: var itemId = $display.getView().getItem().getId();

Answer (score 2):

If you have the component (as an object), you can get it's schema id as Peter indicated. If you only have the component id, you can load the component and through that get to the schema.

When you need to load any item, you have to be aware that it's not a synchronous call in the UI API, so you should use delegate methods for that. For example something like this:

```
Example.prototype._loadItemInformation = function Example$_loadItemInformation(itemId, reload) {
    var item = $models.getItem(itemId);
    if (item) {
        var self = this;
        function Example$_loadItemInformation$_onItemLoaded() {
            $evt.removeEventHandler(item, "load", Example$_loadItemInformation$_onItemLoaded);
            // proceed with the actions on the loaded item here
        };

        if (item.isLoaded(true) && !reload) {
            Example$_loadItemInformation$_onItemLoaded();
        }
        else {
            $evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", Example$_loadItemInformation$_onItemLoaded);
            //$evt.addEventHandler(item, "loadfailed", Example$_loadItemInformation$_onItemLoadFailed);
            item.load(reload, $const.OpenMode.VIEW);
        }
    }
};
```

Also be aware the item could fail loading, you should actually also register an event handler for loadfailed (as my example code neglects to do).